# Подключение к базе данных Firebird на php

Tags: php, firebird

Искала ответ на вопрос на форумах, но так и не получилось решить проблему.
Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных Firebird :

```
$database = 'localhost:C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\c336.ru\\1.FDB';
$user     = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$db = ibase_connect($database, $user, $password);
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in C:\OpenServer\domains\c336.ru\view\klienti.php on line 49

Использую php-5.6*64 и в файле php.ini раскоментировала строки:

```
extension=php_interbase.dll 
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

Затем добавила в папку с путем `C:\OpenServer\modules\http\Apache-2.4-x64\bin` файл `fbclient.dll`.

Вычитала, что нужно добавить еще файл `GDS32.DLL` (взяла из `С:\Windows\System32`, но так же пробовала взять из `С:\Windows\SysWOW64`). Но все равно ничего не работает

Comment: соответствующие dll-файлы существуют? если да, то откуда они были взяты?

Comment: Раскоментировала строки в php.ini с путем C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64. Потом проверяла в C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64\ext и раскоментированные extension=php_interbase.dll 
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll там появились. fbclient.dll была взята из C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\WOW64

Comment: OpenServer генерирует конфигурацию PHP из шаблона, лучше раскомментировать там (хоть это и вряд ли сразу решит проблему)

Comment: А где найти этот шаблон?